# Cant load UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, view

Ok, this is really really easy, but even though I went through 100s of tutorials, I still have no idea whats wrong with my app. All I want to do is just to display a table view, even empty, but I get a black screen on the simulator and an exception in the output too.

This is what I did (followed step by step a few tutorials):

1. Open a view based app
2. This is my header:

   ```
        @interface TableViewsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {


    IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
     }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;

    @end
   ```
3. did not do anything in .m besides synthesizing.
4. IB: made 3 connections: delegate, dataSource, and  tblSimpleTable to File's owner.

Yes, I am a beginner, but this is ridiculous...appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: what's the exception you're getting in the output?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TableViewsViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b40480'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a table view has two "delegate" types -- the table view delegate and the table view data source. Your interface is being a delegate, but not a data source, for the table view.

If you add UITableViewDataSource to the interface, i.e.

```
@interface TableViewsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and then compile, you'll probably get errors about missing methods for number of sections and for cell. After you add these to your implementation, the table view should work.

My guess is the table view tries to ask your class for number of sections in the table, and since your class doesn't actually respond to that selector, the code crashes.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Added the UITableViewDataSource and the appropriate methods. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
tblSimpleTable.delegate = self
```

in viewDidLoad

...and ensure you have connected it correctly in interface builder.